# how to GET a Bundle of FHIR that contains both, the Paient details and the Claims he/she has taken?

Tags: hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

If I have a patient `../Patient/f8d8477c-1ef4-4878-abed-51e514bfd91f`,
and a claim `../Claim/<id>` which has a reference to the above patient:

```
"patient": {
       "reference": "f8d8477c-1ef4-4878-abed-51e514bfd91f",
       "display": "John_Smith"
}
```

How do i query FHIR to get a bundle that has the Patient and its associated Claims ?
Do i need to add a **#** in the reference value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either search for the Patient and _revinclude the Claims, or search for the Claims and _include the Patient. I recommend the latter because it allows for pagination if there happen to be a large number of claims - you want the primary results to be what you're paging through, not the include/revinclude.

Patient?_id=f8d8477c-1ef4-4878-abed-51e514bfd91f&_revinclude=Claim:patient

Claim?patient=Patient/f8d8477c-1ef4-4878-abed-51e514bfd91f&_include=Claim:patient